# Alternative performance measures for multiclass classification in caret

Tags: r, r-caret, multiclass-classification

I do want to tune a classification algorithm **predicting probabilities** using `caret`. 
Since my data-set is highly unbalanced, the default `Accuracy` option of `caret` seems not to be so helpful according to this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68702/r-caret-difference-between-roc-curve-and-accuracy-for-classification.

In my specific case, I want to determine the optimal `mtry` parameter of a random forest, which predicts probabilities. I do have 3 classes and a palance ratio of 98.7% - 0.45% -  0.85%. An reproducible example - which has sadely no unbalanced data-set - is given by:

```
library(caret)
data(iris)


control = trainControl(method="CV", number=5,verboseIter = TRUE,classProbs=TRUE)

grid = expand.grid(mtry = 1:3)
rf_gridsearch = train(y=iris[,5],x=iris[-5],method="ranger", num.trees=2000, tuneGrid=grid, trControl=control)
rf_gridsearch
```

So my two questions basically are:

1. What alternative summary metrics besides the `Accuracy` do I have?
   (Using multiROC is not my favourite, due to: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68702/r-caret-difference-between-roc-curve-and-accuracy-for-classification. I think of sth. like a Brier Score)
2. How do I implement them?

Many thanks!

Comment: How many classes and what is the approximate ratio of them?

Comment: Three classes with a ratio of: 98,7% - 0,45% - 0,85%